# How to generate sun-web.xml for a Java Web Application using NetBeans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans, configuration-files

The title says it all.
Is there any plugin for NetBeans 7.0 to generate *sun-web.xml* in a web project?

If yes, please let me know.

Comment: A generic XML editor works just fine for it.

Comment: thanks for answer you mean eclipse XML editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo do not need to install any plugin:

1. Go to `File > New Files > XML > XML Document` from menu.
2. In the first wizard form enter "*sun-xml*" as file name.
3. In Document Type wizard form select DTD-Constrained Document radio button
4. in the DTD Options wizard enter following information:

   **DTD Public ID:** -//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet//EN

   **DTD System ID:** http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd

   **Document Root:** sun-web-app
5. Finally click on the finish button.

You have to know that *glassfish-web.xml* is the new name for *sun-web.xml* and for GlassFish server versions older than 3.1, this file is called *sun-web.xml*. You can create *glassfish-web.xml* using:

```
File > New Files > GlassFish > GlassFish Descriptor
```

Comment: Is there one for tomcat as well ? I want to get rid of session creation.